# Why can't one use airport luggage trolleys when queuing for the immigration counter in an airport?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, luggage, airports

There typically is no available airport luggage trolley that we can bring to the immigration queue after landing to an airport. Why can't one use airport luggage trolleys when queuing for the immigration counter in an airport?

Comment: Is this before or after baggage claim?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan before

Comment: Because there is no luggage to carry to immigration? You get your luggage _after_ immigration.

Comment: @Aganju why do you think airports provide baggage trolleys between the security and the gate when boarding a plane? At that stage, passengers have the same amount of luggage as during the immigration queue.

Comment: I have never seen that happen. I don't know why they would.

Comment: @Aganju you never saw baggage trolleys between the security and the gate when boarding a plane? That's in pretty much almost all (maybe all) large airport.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I'm with Aganju, people should only have on-board luggage post-security so a roll-aboard and a personal item/laptop bag/etc. I've wanted a trolley because my backpack is darn happy, but never seen a trolley post-security at the airports I've been at.

Comment: The only reason they provide the smaller trolleys from security to the gate is so that you can shop more easily and spend more money. This usually doesn't happen between the plane and immigration.

Comment: @jcaron true there is typically no shopping area, but in terms of time spent, immigration can take a while too.

Comment: Yes but they don’t care, they have nothing to sell you so no incentive to make things easier for you at this point, they just want you out of there as quickly as possible. Also I don’t think they would allow you to use the trolleys in the queue or through immigration.

Comment: Also it would be a headache to bring the trolleys to each gate.

Answer (score 5):

The airport probably assumes people can handle one carry-on bag and one personal item each without a trolley. There is often limited space for the immigration queues at busy times, and trolleys significantly increase the queue space per person.

The airports I've arrived at do provide trolleys at international baggage claim, where people will be collecting bigger, heavier bags, and often more than one per person, in addition to their carry-on and personal item.

Comment: "airport probably assumes people can handle one carry-on bag and one personal item each without a trolley." -> I don't think this is true because airports do provide baggage trolleys between the security and the gate when boarding a plane, and typically it's faster to go from the security to the boarding gate than it is to queue for immigration.

Comment: "trolleys significantly increase the queue space per person." -> I'm not sure about that one but perhaps you're right. I'd be curious to have some references that investigated this aspect.

Comment: If nothing else, it seems like it would be really awkward to maneuver a trolley through the maze of snaking rope barriers that you usually see at immigration queues.  The turning radius of a luggage trolley is not so good.

Comment: Some classes of service allow people to bring more than one carry on and one personal item.  But still, however much one *does* "carry on" to the plane, one ought to be able to *carry* it.

Comment: @NateEldredge don't we do the same when checking in luggage?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Can you please name an airport or two that allows luggage trolleys at gates?

Comment: Here are luggage trolleys visible at CPH, non-Schengen area: https://goo.gl/maps/1T3afdQJkYyGr42D8 schengen area: https://goo.gl/maps/aV191MT76x6e34Nm9

Comment: @mkennedy eg TPE or HKG. I'm guessing aside tiny airports don't have it, and perhaps a few large airports don't have any, but that'd be an exception, not the norm

Comment: @phoog It's one thing to be able to carry a backpack for 10 minutes, but a different stress on the body to carry it for one hour while waiting to go through the immigration queue. Also some people have physical conditions that limit their ability to carry heavy objects and it is not acceptable to discriminate against them. With that being said, I'm not here to rant but genuinely understanding the airport companies' mindset.

Comment: @mkennedy AMS - I’ve used them there in both the Schengen and International areas post-security.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I don't think that luggage carts fall under the ADA in the US.  If I'm right about that then failing to provide them is not discriminatory in the US.  Perhaps that explains why they typically cost $5 to rent in US airports while they are free of charge in European airports.  Are they in fact considered to be a required accommodation in Europe?

Comment: I put my carry-on down when waiting in line, and only lift it for seconds at a time to move forward. The general way airports deal with disabilities is to provide wheelchair service. That works for invisible, as well as visible, disabilities. My mother used to use it because she had a heart condition that limited her walking distance.

Answer (score 2):

## Between areas of the airport

Some airports allow trolleys through passport control, check the text in this picture: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Copenhagen_Kastrup2.JPG
This is between Schengen and non-Schengen part of Copenhagen airport.

In the other direction you can't see anything that will stop your trolley and you also see a passenger queuing with a trolley:
https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:File-Copenhagen_Kastrup2.JPG

## When exiting the airport

At some airports immigration control happens just before baggage reclaim. Bringing the trolley through to baggage reclaim would mean that it must have to go through a security check to get back airside. This would be too costly.

Another option is that you leave the trolley when you are in the front of the immigration queue resulting in a lot of trolleys ending up in an unwanted place so staff would constantly need to clear the area from trolleys, which would also be too costly.

A third option would be to have an airside area after immigration where you leave your trolley. Then there would need to be one way gates into baggage reclaim. Again too costly.

Answer (score 1):

To slow you down.

Most of the routes and facilities between the gate and collecting your checked baggage is designed to slow you down, so the wait at the various points is minimised as much as possible.

By lengthening the routes and making people carry their own baggage, it spreads out the congestion at immigration etc, making it easier for the pre-immigration observations to happen and the backlog through immigration to be as small as possible.

There is a lot of thought that goes into passenger flow through airports at various points, and the airports goals are not necessarily the same as your goals.  People tend to perceive inconveniences in different ways - the queue at immigration is often disconnected in people’s minds from the time it took to get there, so forcing people to spread out and arrive gradually rather than bunching up and arriving all at once tends to manipulate people’s feelings because they think the immigration line is shorter...